# how to extract specific digits in R (including NA)

Tags: r, numbers, extract, na, col

I've extracted the specific value from dataframe successfully in R. However, there's another problem that I can't solve. If there's any help that would be appreciated.

the raw data looks like as below:
I'd like to extract 6 digits numbers from every rows, but there's NA some rows in the frame. It looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  v1=c('aa',438652,22,01,54,5892),
  v2=c(343012,45,'pi',75,2001,3),
  v3=c(56,'hi',78,670934,77,90),
  v4=c('cc','go',35,4458,40021,576),
  v5=c('ya',435,05,44,90032,6021),
  v6=c(432,21,3013,5,302001,'fgh'))
```

However,

I'd like to extract "6 digits numbers" out into another new frame and    ***also included with "NA"***

It's looked like this:

```
new <- data.frame(
  v7=c(343012,438652,NA,670934,302001,NA))
```

Does anyone have any ideas? That would be a great appreciation !!

Comment: Maybe `df %>% unite("v7", everything()) %>% mutate(v7 = str_extract(v7, "\\d{6}"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that we need to extract per row

```
out <- data.frame(v7 = apply(df, 1, function(x) grep("^\\d{6}", x,
     value = TRUE)[1]))
```

---

Another option is `coalesce` after replacing all values other than 6 digits to `NA`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
   mutate_all(~ replace(as.character(.),
         str_detect(., "^\\d{6}$", negate = TRUE), NA)) %>% 
   transmute(v7 = coalesce(!!! .))
```

Answer (score 2):

To my opinion, @Akrun's solution is  the best and most elegant one, but if you want (or you don't like regex expressions) you can do in another way by looking for number bigger than 100000.

so, first convert the dataframe in numeric and extract number bigger than 100000 and add NA in empty cases.

So, it should look like:

```r
df = data.frame(apply(df,2,as.numeric))
v7 = data.frame("v7" = unlist(lapply(apply(df,1,function(x) x[which(x>=100000)]), function(v){v = c(v,rep(NA,1-length(v)))})))
```

And you get:

```r
> v7
      v7
1 343012
2 438652
3     NA
4 670934
5 302001
6     NA
```